# Qual è il significato di "raspare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *L'amica geniale* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> Attraverso quelle aperture il buio poteva prenderci all’improvviso le bambole, a volte al sicuro tra le nostre braccia, più spesso messe di proposito accanto al reticolo ritorto e quindi esposte al respiro freddo dello scantinato, ai rumori minacciosi che ne venivano, ai fruscii, agli scricchiolii, al **raspare**.

Il brano cerca di spiegare le paure infantili di due bambine che giocano con le loro bambine accanto a uno scantinato.

Ho cercato il verbo "raspare" in alcuni dizionari, ma non riesco a capire il suo significato nel brano precedente. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 2):

Raspare è l'azione che compiono alcuni animali, nell'atto di raspare la terra, ovvero utilizzare le zampe per "grattare" il terreno.

Da qui il verbo viene trasformato in un sostantivo con il significato di "rumore di zampe che grattano contro qualcosa", spesso usato anche in senso figurato.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE e grazie della risposta!

Answer (score 1):

Dal contesto, direi che "raspare" va inteso nel senso di "rumore di unghie/zampe che grattano la porta". Immagino che tale rumore sia considerato minaccioso perché indica che un animale sta tentando di "aprire" la porta ed entrare. Molte generazioni di bambini sono cresciute con la paura di un lupo che entra in casa e mangia i bambini, per via delle molte favole che lo raccontano.

Answer (score 0):

Raspare indica l'azione di levigare con una raspa.

A sua volta la raspa è un utensile che serve per levigare il legno e materiali duri.

Il rumore della raspa può essere a seconda la superficie dove utilizzata più o meno stridulo, di conseguenza il riferimento al `raspare` indica dei suoni che per un bambino possono incutere timore.

Se vai [qui](http://www.mcello63.com/suonerie_varie/page_05.htm) e selezioni il file `39 - FABBRICA FALEGNAMERIA.mp3` ti renderai conto del rumore della raspa su del legno e potrai assocaire l'immaginazione del bambino che ha timore.